# Stream reader cannot get the text from file text to a textbox

Tags: c#, filestream

```
try
{
    Form frmShow = new Form();
    TextBox txtShowAll = new TextBox();
    frmShow.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
    frmShow.Font = this.Font;
    frmShow.Size = this.Size;
    frmShow.Icon = this.Icon;
    frmShow.Text = "All data";
    txtShowAll.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    txtShowAll.Multiline = true;
    frmShow.Controls.Add(txtShowAll);
    frmShow.ShowDialog();

    StreamReader r = new StreamReader("empData.txt");
    string strShowAllData = r.ReadToEnd();                
    txtShowAll.Text = strShowAllData;
    r.Close();
}
catch (Exception x)
{
     MessageBox.Show(x.Message);
}
```

I sure that is the file name is correct
when I run the program it shows an empty text box.

The result
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just noticed you are adding text to the textbox after showing the form in dialog mode. Why don't you move the frmShow.ShowDialog(); to the end of the try block just like I have done it in the code below, and make sure the empData.txt exists at its path.

```
        try
        {
            Form frmShow = new Form();
            TextBox txtShowAll = new TextBox();
            frmShow.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            frmShow.Font = this.Font;
            frmShow.Size = this.Size;
            frmShow.Icon = this.Icon;
            frmShow.Text = "All data";
            txtShowAll.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            txtShowAll.Multiline = true;
            frmShow.Controls.Add(txtShowAll);

            StreamReader r = new StreamReader("empData.txt");
            string strShowAllData = r.ReadToEnd();
            txtShowAll.Text = strShowAllData;
            r.Close();

            frmShow.ShowDialog();
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(x.Message);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

As noted other places, the actual problem stems from the show dialog blocking before you can execute your dialog

There are a couple of things here

1. Why don't you create a dedicated Form i.e `MyDeciatedShowAllForm`, instead of dynamically creating it
2. If you are using something that implements `IDisposable`, Its best to use a `using` statement

**Example**

```
using(var r = new StreamReader("empData.txt"))
{
    string strShowAllData = r.ReadToEnd();                
    txtShowAll.Text = strShowAllData;
}
```

3. Why don't you use `File.ReadAllText` instead, save your self some printable characters

**Example**

```
string strShowAllData = File.ReadAllText(path);
```

4. You probably need to set the TextBox to [MultiLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12w624ff(v=vs.110).aspx)

**Example**

```
// Set the Multiline property to true.
textBox1.Multiline = true;
// Add vertical scroll bars to the TextBox control.
textBox1.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical;
// Allow the RETURN key to be entered in the TextBox control.
textBox1.AcceptsReturn = true;
// Allow the TAB key to be entered in the TextBox control.
textBox1.AcceptsTab = true;
// Set WordWrap to true to allow text to wrap to the next line.
textBox1.WordWrap = true;
// Show all data
textBox1.Text = strShowAllData;
```

5. Why don't you check if the file exists first using [File.Exists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists(v=vs.110).aspx)

**Exmaple**

```
if(!File.Exists("someFile.txt"))
{
    MessageBox.Show(!"oh nos!!!!! the file doesn't exist");
    return;
}
```

6. **Lastly, and this is one you need to remember,** you need to learn how to use the debugger and breakpoints, [Navigating through Code with the Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx). I mean, you should have known if there is text or not in your text file if you had just put a breakpoint on `txtShowAll.Text = strShowAllData;` there should be no doubt in your mind or ours.